# Unable to access UserMin/UserMax in eventObject of click event in RangeSelector in Highcharts

Tags: events, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am working on a task where I have implemented RangeSelector in Highcharts(in React using functional components). I have implemented a click event for month category. In the event handler I need to access UserMin and UserMax values which are inside the event object present as argument. But, I am unable to access only those two properties in the event object which has the form

```
PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}
```

You can check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pravindvarma/k65eq92v/

When you click on the month button, the console shows this object. When I click on YTD, it shows undefined for e.xAxis.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `afterSetExtremes` event, check if it is triggered by range selector button and get the `userMin` and `userMax` values.

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e){
                if (e.trigger === 'rangeSelectorButton') {
                    const { userMin, userMax } = e;
                    
                    console.log(userMin, userMax);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/362gv98u/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tried here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yrtt1g?file=index.js
It is not working with React functional component.

Comment: Hi @Pravin Varma, You didn't use stock chart, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-x1mob?file=/demo.jsx everything works as expected.